# Sefer HaMiddot - Has anyone successfully sourced each aphorism?

Tags: sources-mekorot, jewish-books, middos-character-traits, breslov, aphorisms-adages

Sefer HaMiddot A.K.A. Aleph-Bet Book (Sefer Ha-Alef Bet, [Book of Traits](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/097976551X)), was Rebbe Nachman’s first work, a collection of aphorisms on the various character traits, positive and negative, as well as other aspects of the spiritual life of the Jew. The first part was written when he was in his youth; the latter part was written when he was already well-known.

Has anyone listed (via book or online) the source for each aphorism?

Online copy of the book [here](http://www.nanach.org/books/sefer-hamedot.pdf).

Comment: There's a printing in my Beit Knesset that has sources made by someone of note, but I forget who. He found sources for many of the aphorisms, but not all.

Comment: http://www.zissil.com/topics/Sefer-Hamidot#Sources_and_Footnotes

Comment: There are various eds. with MM from R. Nachman of Tsherin and/or R. Tzadok of Lublin (Yes THAT one!)- and there's a particularly well-invested ed. by Toras HaNetzach